# migrate products from magento to wordpress (csv file)

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

Is there any possibility to migrate a big list(2500+++) of products(labels, categories, images ...etc) from Magento to Wordpress without plugins ( because they require access if it's not the case then plugins are welcomed).
N.B 1: there's no access to magento website
N.B 2: Full access on wordpress

Comment: If there is access to the database, you could create a query to export the product database into a csv format in the way wordpress need it (It would be a very complex query because the EAV model).

Comment: the problem is that i do not have access to magento website

Comment: I don't see another easy solution then. The only thing that came to my mind is to create an script which scrapts the whole content from the website but only will be reading the info available in the frontend.
Greetings.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check that.